# Get the command line arguments in NetBeans 7.1.2

Tags: netbeans, command-line-arguments

I am using NetBeans 7.1.2. My error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:17)
Java Result: 1
```

My program is:

```
package javaapplication1;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        int a=Integer.parseInt(ar[1]);

        System.out.println(a);
        // TODO: Code application logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the first parameter is `ar[0]`, for example in the command line below `ar[0]` is `"123"`:

```
java JavaApplication1 123
```

See [this web page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for more information on Java command-line arguments.